# Check if i use sudo or su

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I want a script shell make the user use su not sudo

I want a script check if i use sudo or su in my command, like :

```
if [ "$USER" != "root" -a "$0" = "sudo" ];then

    echo "You have to run this script as a root \"Use : su \" "

fi
```

I know is wrong, can anybody help me ??

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You may want to check this out: http://serverfault.com/questions/568627/can-a-program-tell-it-is-being-run-under-sudo

Comment: i know all the example to run as a root but i want create a script for arch and arch u can use sudo and su so how do i know when he use sudo and when he use su

Comment: did you read my last comment ??

Comment: `su` runs a shell under a different user id; `sudo` runs an arbitrary command under a different user id, so `su root` and `sudo -u root sh` essentially do the exact same thing. Why do you need to differentiate between two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the $EUID since the effective user id will always be 0 for sudo :)
Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ $EUID = 0 ]]; then
    echo "sudo!"
else
    echo "not sudo!"
fi
```

Edit:

above doesn't work, but if you just want to check this from a simple bash script you could do this hack:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ $EUID = 0 && "$(ps -o comm= | sed -n '1p')" = "su" ]]; then
    echo "sudo!"
else
    echo "not sudo!"
fi
```

Will obviously not recognize normal root shells, but actual su use is properly recognized. ( could break when called by another script :/ )

really dirty and not stable against nested su use (where sudo could still pass when ran from nested su) , it might suffice to do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ $EUID = 0 && "$(ps -o comm= | grep su | sed -n '1p')" = "su" ]]; then
    echo "sudo!"
else
    echo "not sudo!"
fi
```

... admittedly a solution from the (NOT OK!) category ...

Comment: Thank you so much but i know this example ; i want the user even if he use _sudo_ its have to get **Error** until he use su

Comment: What if you replace the variable with __$SUDO_USER__ ? and test the result length ?

Comment: Just tried that( $SUDO_USER), not working. It's still returning the normal user even in su for me :/

Comment: Sorry but is the same :'(

Comment: sorry is the same ok thanks anyway is so happy to give my question your time thanks you so much

Comment: np, sorry this seemed a ton more trivial ( and probably is :) eventually ) than it turned out. In any case added a hack that should work 100% but with the mentioned false positives :/